# ¿Cómo creo un archivo .jar ejecutable de un proyecto Gradle en netbeans?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

terminé un proyecto Gradle en Java, y ahora mismo no se como crear un archivo `.jar`.

Mi proyecto contiene varios packages, clases e imágenes.
¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: https://www.arquitecturajava.com/que-es-gradle/ Ahí te pone como generar el .jar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con los siguientes comandos dentro de la carpeta del proyecto:

```
gradle clean
```

Y luego:

```
gradle fatJar
```

Debería crear una carpeta llamada `libs` con el jar dentro

Comment: Donde tengo que poner los comandos?

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta donde tienes el proyecto, claramente desde una terminal